# How to get the AnalyserNode's frequencyBinCount from a given time

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I'm trying to draw a waveform on a canvas only when a user seeks through an audio file.

So I'm figuring out a way to get the AnalyserNode's frequencyBinCount from an audio element from a given time.

So whenever the user is seeking through the audio, the visualization will get updated drawn. It does not matter if the audio is playing or not.

Is this even possible or is there an alternative way to get what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by getting the `frequencyBinCount` from an audio element?  When you set the `fftSize` for the `AnalyserNode`, the `frequencyBinCount` is set too.  This is independent of the audio element.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear


I need to find a way to get the frequencyBinCount from the audio file when the audio is not playing, but idle on a different time than 0.


So whenever the user is seeking through the audio, the visualization will get updated on mouse release. Even when the audio is not playing.


A strange request but I need it for my use case and I was wondering if and how it was possible.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  The frequency bin count has nothing to do with the audio element and whether it's playing or not. You set the fftSize which sets the frequencyBinCount.  This is just basically how fine a resolution you want for the frequency samples.  If the audio element isn't playing, you don't need to adjust this.  You'll just get an array of frequencyBinCount values from that analyzer that is all zeros.

Comment: I think I lack a lot of knowledge on this topic, my apologies. I'm trying to get the frequency of a given time of an audio file. 

In a realtime setting/when the audio is being played, I would use the frequencyBinCount of an AnalyserNode. Ex; `new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);` And use this information to draw a waveform on a canvas.

The goal now is to draw a waveform when a user seeks through an audio element, even when the audio is idle or paused. Instead of drawing the waveform in a realtime setting via the AnalyserNode, when the audio is being played.

Comment: I understand now.  Basically, you can't really do this unless you have a way to get the audio data from the paused audio element.  I'm not very familiar with that so I don't know if that's possible or not.  Sorry.